# How to convert a list of dicts to multiple dicts with tuple of combination as the key?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a dict which looks something like this

```
[{'2013-01': 0.4,
  '2013-02': 0.5,
  'id': 1},
{'2013-01': 0.1,
  '2013-02': 0.4,
  'id': 2},]
```

How do I convert it something like this:

```
Format: {('yyyy-mm', id): value}

{('2013-01', 1): 0.4,
('2013-02', 1): 0.5,
('2013-01', 2): 0.1,
('2013-01', 2): 0.4
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate through the list of dictionaries:

```py
res = {}
for d in d_list:
    id_ = d.pop('id')
    for k, v in d.items():
        res[(k, id_)] = v
```

or with a dict comprehension, slightly more concise:

```py
res = {}
for d in d_list:
    id_ = d.pop('id')
    res.update({(k, id_): v for k, v in d.items()})
```

Answer (score 3):

Using dict comprehension

```
{(k,d['id']):d[k] for k in d for d in my_lis if k!='id'}
```

Output:

```
{('2013-01', 1): 0.4,
 ('2013-01', 2): 0.1,
 ('2013-02', 1): 0.5,
 ('2013-02', 2): 0.4}
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly there are a plenty of ways of accomplishing this task, I have provided to you very high-level solution:

```
myList = [{'2013-01': 0.4,
  '2013-02': 0.5,
'2016-05': 0.4,
  'id': 1},
{'2013-05': 0.1,
  '2013-02': 0.4,
'2017-05': 0.4,
  'id': 2},
{'2013-06': 0.1,
'2014-05': 0.4,
'2018-05': 0.4,
  'id': 3}

];

def formatmyList(arr, numberOfDifferentYears):
    if(not(isinstance(arr, list))):
        raise Exception("Not List.")

    __dict = dict.__new__(dict, ())
    for item in arr:
        name = None
        keys = item.keys()
        keys.sort() # make sure to sort 'cause of python's built-in problems
        for i in range(numberOfDifferentYears):
                try:
                        name = str(keys[i])
                        if(name!="id"):
                                __dict[tuple((str(keys[i]), item[keys[i]]))] = item[keys[keys.__len__()-1]]
                except IndexError:
                         pass
    return __dict

print(formatmyList(myList, 3)) # e.g. three different years
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use list comprehension here:

```
{
    (k, subd['id']): v
    for subd in data
    for k, v in subd.items()
    if k != 'id'
}
```

this produces:

```
>>> {
...     (k, subd['id']): v
...     for subd in data
...     for k, v in subd.items()
...     if k != 'id'
... }
{('2013-01', 1): 0.4, ('2013-02', 1): 0.5, ('2013-01', 2): 0.1, ('2013-02', 2): 0.4}
```

Or we can use pandas here:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('id').stack().reset_index().set_index(['level_1', 'id'])[0].to_dict()
```

This gives us:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('id').stack().reset_index().set_index(['level_1', 'id'])[0].to_dict()
{('2013-01', 1): 0.4, ('2013-02', 1): 0.5, ('2013-01', 2): 0.1, ('2013-02', 2): 0.4}
```